# После изменения URL портала Sharepoint ссылается на старый адрес

Tags: url, sharepoint, iis

Доброго дня! С Sharepoint'ом близкого знакомства не водил, и вот столкнулся с проблемой:  есть корпоративный портал на `Sharepoint`, работал по адресу (условно) `http://portal-1.ru`. Шеф решил привести все к некоему единообразию и перенести портал на адрес, созвучный с именем сайта компании. Сделали субдомен `portal.corp.ru`, в центре управления `Sharepoint` изменили `URL` веб-приложения на новый, в `IIS'е` сделали привязку к новому `URL`. Попробовали - работает. Вроде бы и все, но нет.

Проблема в том, что некоторые ссылки (например, профили пользователей) отсылают на старый `URL`! Из-за чего постоянно вылезают ошибки, что, мол, недоступна страница. И никак не получается найти, где же эти ссылки прописаны.

Если кто-то подскажет - благодарность моя будет безгранична. :)
Хотя бы в какую сторону копать...
Заранее большое человеческое спасибо!

Comment: Если кто смотрит, что вопрос задан уже достаточно давно и не отвечает - отвечайте! Вопрос актуален :)

Answer (score 1):

За сайты профилей отвечает отдельная служба-приложение. В вашем случае, если не используете профили полноценно, лучше просто выключить.

Точное название: *Служба управления профилями: User Profile Service Application*. Там все эти ссылки редактируются.

Comment: Точное название - Служба управления профилями: User Profile Service Application, там все эти ссылки редактируются.